# AJAX does not respond to form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I wrote a toy program to learn AJAX, which is to submit the user registration form to web server, however, the program on the server side cannot receive the data. I guess the error is on the following JS code using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#registerForm').submit(function() {
    var formData = $('#registerForm').serialize();
    $.post('/admin/user/signup', formData, registerResults);
    },

    registerResults: function() {
            console.log("register success!");
        }  // end of registerResults

});  // end of ready
```

The corresponding html form is as following:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id='registerForm' method='POST' action="/admin/user/signup">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="fullname">Fullname: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <input class="form-control" type='text' id="fullname" name='fullname' placeholder="Full Name" />
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="username">Username: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input class="form-control" type='text' id="username" name='username' placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type='submit' value="Submit" class="register-form-button" form='user-create-form' />
        </div>
    </form>
```

can someone help me with my JS code using jQuery? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your JS code is syntactically invalid. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) and have a look at a [JS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) to learn the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Felix said, your JavaScript syntax is invalid.  Open up the JS console and refresh the page, and you'll see syntax errors.

Here's a shot at fixing it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#registerForm').submit(function() {
        var formData = $('#registerForm').serialize();
        $.post('/admin/user/signup', formData)
            .done(registerResults)
            .fail(registerError);
    });

    function registerResults() {
        console.log("register success!");
    }  

    function registerError() {
        console.log("There was an error");
    }

});
```

Comment: Sure thing!  Note that this is using the .done() and .fail() promises instead of the traditional callback as the last parameter, which I think is a much cleaner way to think about handling the results (or failure) of an AJAX request.

Answer (score 1):

The `registerResults` function was a `namespace` function based on the formatting, but you only need a standard function like the below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#registerForm').submit(function () {
        var formData = $('#registerForm').serialize();
        $.post('/admin/user/signup', formData, registerResults);
    });

    function registerResults() {
        console.log("register success!");
    } // end of registerResults

}); // end of ready
```